# Solr cache is not updating , if i recreates the index with the new values

Tags: java, solr, lucene

We are using the auto-complete feature of solr, where the data is loaded from the index. 
The index was accessed by the symbolic link (Files.createSymbolicLink)

Suppose we are recreating the index again and updating this SymbolicLink, this is a scheduler task that runs for every 5 mins, to check for the index updates.

The issue is even the index gets updated successfully the changes are note reflected in the solr cache.

Do we need to manually reimport the index in java code;

Thanks in Advance,
Ragahvan

Comment: Are you swapping the symlink beneath Solr and except Solr to use the new files because you swapped the symlink?

Comment: Thanks, Mats, Actually we are reusing the Lucene index, which was created for the other module. The symlink is created to this index file and in Lucene's side we are don't need any restart. In the case of Solr, we are just over-riding the handleRequestBody of the search request handler class, where the index reading mechanism was handled internally.